# How to handle case where 0, 1, or 2 rows are returned from ResultSet

Tags: java, resultset

I have a `ResultSet resultSet` that can potentially return 0, 1, or 2 rows from an executed query.

```java
Map<String, Integer> results = new HashMap<>();
if (!resultSet.next()){
     // handle case where there are no rows
     results.put("count1", 0)
     results.put("count2", 0)
}
else {
     resultSet.beforeFirst();
     while (resultSet.next()) {
     // handle case where there are 1 or 2 rows
     results.put(resultSet.getInt("column1") == 0 ? "count1" : "count2", resultSet.getInt("column2"));
     }
}
```

When there are no rows or 1 row, I get this exception `org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0`. Shouldn't my if condition handle no rows and shouldn't my else condition also handle 1 row. My else condition is able to handle 2 rows.

Comment: Try always iterating over the results, then afterward check if the Map is empty and set some default values.

Comment: Also `results.put(resultSet.getInt("column1") == 0 ? "count1" : "count2", resultSet.getInt("column2"));` uses "column1" or "column2" as the Map key, but the Map value is always `resultSet.getInt("column2")`.  Is that intended?

Comment: @AndrewS, if I iterate over the results using while(resultSet.next()), I'll get the `EmptyResultDataAccessException` on a query result of no rows. Yeah that's intended :)

Comment: Look for examples - `while (resultSet.next()) { ... }` should work.  What is the DB?

Comment: You could increment a counter and fill your map up with 0s while it is still smaller than 3 after looping over your result set, if that is what you are trying to do. Looping over the result set as in Andrews comment should indeed work just fine.

Comment: "If I iterate over the results using while(resultSet.next()), I'll get the EmptyResultDataAccessException`": no you won't. Never seen it in 2)+ years of JDBC. You might get that from some intermediate framework, or your own code, but JDBC does not throw that exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being how I was calling the query from another class. I was using the `QueryExecutor` method `queryForObject` that expects a single result to be returned, so when my query executed and no rows returned, `EmptyResultDataAccessException` got thrown. When I changed the method to `query`, then:

```java
while (resultSet.next()) {
     results.put(resultSet.getInt("column1") == 0 ? "count1" : "count2", resultSet.getInt("column2"));
}
```

worked with no issues since the while loop won't execute if there are no rows.

Comment: So your comment above "if I iterate over the results using while(resultSet.next()), I'll get the EmptyResultDataAccessException`" is not correct.